# What Java Selector classes are available?

Tags: java, nio, epoll

My understanding is that on sufficiently recent versions of Linux, the default selector is a class that uses an epoll implementation, whereas on older versions (older kernels? I'm not sure), a class that uses a select or poll-based implementation is used.

According to the docs, it's also possible to set the java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider property to override the default selector class.

Is it possible to force a non-epoll implementation by setting the property to the name of a provided (but non-default) class?
What classes are provided as part of the standard java libs that can act as selectors?

It's not important that the final program work well cross-platform. This is intended merely to compare the performance between the two implementations in a controlled environment.

Answer (score 0):

You only get one `Selector` implementation per JRE. You won't be able to combine or alternate them, unless you write your own, and then you won't be able to use it with `SocketChannels` from the default provider so you'd have to implement those as well, and `ServerSocketChannels` etc.